# Flexbox: while a group of items is at the very center of the page, put at single item at the bottom

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have used **Bootstrap 4** and some custom CSS to make a hero section with all its items but one centered horizontally *and* vertically.

The exception is one item I want to align at the **bottom of the page** and still keep it *centered horizontally*.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
a.inherit {
  color: inherit;
}
a.nounderline, a.nounderlie:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.hero img {
  width: 100%;
}
.hero.type-text h1 {
  color: #000;
}
.hero.hero-short {
  max-height: 768px;
}
section.type-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.type-text h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
section.type-text p {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.allcases {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <section class="container d-flex hero type-text">
    <div>
      <h4 class="text-center m-0">Next item</h4>
      <h1 class="display-1 text-center">
        <a class="inherit nounderlie" href="#">Lorem</a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <p class="allcases">
      <a class="inherit" href="#">See all items</a>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

"See all items" does stay to the bottom (thanks to `margin-top: auto`), but it is **not centered**. Changing the flex-direction from row to column messes the whole layout so it is not the way to go.

What is viable solution?

Comment: `flex-direction: column` is the obvious solution here. How does it mess up your whole layout?

Comment: if this is your desired result you have to go with flex-flow: column https://s15.postimg.cc/5isp3inob/image.png or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @evayly Yes, this is what I want to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `flex-direction: column` for this. This is an ideal use-case for it. Using `row` layout to achieve what you want, i.e. have the items horizontally centered is not viable. You'd be better off not using `flex` at all, and using margins instead. If you really wish to use `flex-direction: row` then the only solution I can think of is either to use `position: absolute` or a negative margin. Wouldn't recommend it though, since what you want can so easily be accomplished just by using `flex-direction: column`.

Here is the result I achieved just by changing 2 properties.  [image]

Update styling to

```
// Only added flex-direction: column to this
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

// This is to target the first div, i.e. the div that contains next item and Lorem, since the div doesn't have a class.
.hero > div { 
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather simple. Change the flex-flow of your container to column.

```
flex-flow:column;
```

Now you have two flex-items: The div, containing your Title and the other links and the footer-p. The first trick is to make your div grow, while the p-tag stays the same. So assign

```
flex: 1 auto;
```

to your div and

```
flex: 0 auto;
```

to your p-tag. 
After doing so you have to add

```
display: flex; 
justify-content: center; 
flex-flow: column;
```

to your div, too. Making it a flex-box itself. 
Your p-tag doesnt require more attention, you can also remove the unnecessary margins.

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow wrapping and set a width to the div suppose to stand at top

to allow wrapping, use a class

```
 <section class="container d-flex hero type-text flex-wrap">
```

for the di, you can do :

```
.hero>div {
  width:100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
a.inherit {
  color: inherit;
}
a.nounderline, a.nounderlie:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.hero>div {
  width:100%;
}
.hero img {
  width: 100%;
}
.hero.type-text h1 {
  color: #000;
}
.hero.hero-short {
  max-height: 768px;
}
section.type-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.type-text h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
section.type-text p {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.allcases {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <section class="container d-flex hero type-text flex-wrap">
    <div>
      <h4 class="text-center m-0">Next item</h4>
      <h1 class="display-1 text-center">
        <a class="inherit nounderlie" href="#">Lorem</a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <p class="allcases">
      <a class="inherit" href="#">See all items</a>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Another option is to use the `flex-column` class

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
a.inherit {
  color: inherit;
}
a.nounderline, a.nounderlie:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
}
.hero.type-text h1 {
  color: #000;
}
.hero.hero-short {
  max-height: 768px;
}
section.type-text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.type-text h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
section.type-text p {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.allcases {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <section class="container d-flex flex-column hero type-text ">
    <div>
      <h4 class="text-center m-0">Next item</h4>
      <h1 class="display-1 text-center">
        <a class="inherit nounderlie" href="#">Lorem</a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <p class="allcases">
      <a class="inherit" href="#">See all items</a>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

in both example, margin of allcases is reset to :

```
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
```

to stick it at bottom of container, no matter the flex-direction.